# Why does D-Link's site not have firmware for the DIR-615 M1 router?

Tags: wireless-router, download, firmware

I'm on a network with a D-Link 615 router, with hardware version M1, firmware revision 1.0.0. I wanted to update the router to a new firmware revision, so I visited the [official page](https://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DIR-615) for DIR-615 on D-Link's site.

Well, there's a drop-down box there for hardware versions, and - M1 doesn't exist!

What do I do? How can I update the firmware?

Comment: Ask dlink?.....

Comment: @DavidPostill: I did something else, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific hardware version is apparently attributed to D-Link Russia (says so on the web interface); and it was bought in Israel. The D-Link Russia site has a DIR 615 page:

http://www.dlink.ru/il/products/5/2067_o.html

which sends you to an Israeli site:

https://www.support.dlink.co.il/routers

and after some navigation there, you're led to a Firmware download page:

ftp://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/Router/DIR-615/Firmware/

which has a folder for the M1 version. In there I found an image for Firmware v2.0.17, and have managed to install it without bricking my router. For now.

Answer (score 0):

The situation for the DIR-615 rev H (H1/H2) firmware as well as some others are somewhat similar. They may be found in Germany at www.d-link.de. The HW rev B, D, H & Q are all there, rev B being the only one also available at the .com-site.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Make it one and I'll upvote it :-)